# Why does my hot water heater flame and pilot go out?

Tags: water-heater

Why would Kenmore water heater it lights then burner comes on until tank is all hot but after that it won't light again and flame goes all the way out and then I have to manual light the pilot again?

Comment: Can you add a model number?

Answer (score 1):

Pilot light thermocouple or valve controller.

Cheapest one to try first is the pilot light thermocouple. All the box stores and most hardware stores have them.